# How do I get the content inside window.data with beautiful soup and jsonify it so I can choose what key and value I want to print?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I didn't know how to put the title, so it's rather long. Feel free to edit it.

I am trying to scrape data from this site, but I can't figure out how to access the individual keys and values within the 'window.data' with beautiful soup.

I'd like to for example get the value of yyuid, birthday, etc.

The code is as such:

```
import urllib.request
import urllib.error
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

username = "itsahardday"
url = "https://likee.video/@" + username # profile url - https://likee.video/account_name

def get_profile_html():
    '''
    Get profile data from HTML - https://likee.video/account_name
    :return:
    '''
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.read(), "html.parser")
    results = soup.select_one("script:-soup-contains('userinfo')").string
    print(results)

get_profile_html()
```

Preferable I would like to have it as JSON, but any solution is welcomed.

In advance, thank you for your help!

Comment: you were almost there! return the results and then split it based on the need, and then load that string as JSON. Once you have JSON, filter the data as needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tweaked your code. return from the function.

```
import urllib.request
import urllib.error
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

username = "itsahardday"
url = "https://likee.video/@" + username # profile url - https://likee.video/account_name

def get_profile_html():
    '''
    Get profile data from HTML - https://likee.video/account_name
    :return:
    '''
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.read(), "html.parser")
    results = soup.select_one("script:-soup-contains('userinfo')").string
    print(results)
    return results # add return

res=get_profile_html() # save the result
```

then , convert to JSON

```
import json # import
json.loads(res.split(";")[0].split("window.data =")[1])['userinfo']
```

Comment: Sorry for reviving this thread. Idk if it is against good practice or if I should actually open a new question. But it makes more sense to me, to ask you, since you helped me with my initial question. Is it possible you can try username="887573847"? I gives an error, and I can't figure out how to solve it. So if you have a solution to the error, then maybe you can update your answer to solve this issue? Thank you very much for your kind help!

Comment: I have made a new post about it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70872275/how-to-correcly-split-the-beautifulsoup-response-to-json

Comment: logic was not generic :( , it fails due to `;` in value `"nick_name":"࿇$k&iexcl;pp&pound;r࿇✅` . let me think about it.

Comment: try this pls `res=get_profile_html() # save the result
res=(res.split("};")[0]+ "}").split("window.data =")[1]
#res
json.loads(res)['userinfo']`

Comment: seems to work great! thank you.